# why we have to extends Servlet or GenericServlet or HttpServlet to create servlet app and with out extending this can we develop our Servlet app?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

what is the requirement to extend  Servlet or GenericServlet or HttpServlet, I will write entire logic which is useful to create servlet but why we have to extends,without extends its not possible to creates Servlet app?

Comment: Let me ask you a counter question. Why do you need the JDK? you could just write your code in notepad and ask your OS to go figure?

Answer (score 0):

Because they define the methods (`service()`, `doPost()` etc.) which are called by the application server to start executing your code.

Otherwise the application server wouldn't know which method to call, but since your servlet extends one of the existing servlet classes, the application server can pass the execution to the `service()` method which is guaranteed to exist.

You can't develop a *servlet* without extending one of those classes, but there are plenty of frameworks that allow you to write classes not extending servlet, which are then called based on other (framework specific) configuration.